# Get file of size and higher

Tags: linux, command-line

i'm trying to print the files that are of a size or higher but i don't get how find -size work i tried this.

```
find -size>100
```

But it still prints file smaller then 100 byte. So how do i do this?

Comment: The command you have posted will not run in any case. You are not setting a size limit, you are redirecting the output to a file called ">". Well, you would if you were to add a space. As it is, you'll just get an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find -size +100c`

The + is equivalent to "greater than", and the "c" suffix indicates bytes (characters) rather than the default 512-byte blocks. Check `man find` for more information about the different size suffixes that can be used.